# MediaElement.js with Chrome fails to download webm file if listed after mp4

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, mediaelement.js

When I use MediaElement.js and list first the mp4 file and then webm, then it doesn't play anything in Chrome (11.0.686.3 dev).
It works fine in Safari/FF/Opera.
It works fine in Chrome if I list mp4 first and webm second but don't call mediaelementplayer, using native HTML5 video.
It also works fine in Chrome (and others) if I call mediaelementplayer but list webm file first.
I've tried all variations and can't figure out this behavior.
I got around it on by changing source order on server side for Chrome, but i'm not a fan of that solution.
If anyone has any ideas I'd be grateful.

My HTML

```
<video width="475" height="275" controls="controls">  
    <source src="/media/BetterDays.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />   
    <source src="/media/BetterDays.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>  
    <source src="/media/BetterDays.theora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />

   <!-- Flash fallback -->  
   <object width="475" height="275" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/javascripts/flashmediaelement.swf">  
        <param name="movie" value="/javascripts/flashmediaelement.swf" />  
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=/images/better_poster_200.jpg&file=/media/BetterDays.mp4" />  
    </object>  
    <!-- Image as a last resort -->  
    <img src="/images/better_poster_200.jpg" width="475" height="275" title="No video playback capabilities" />  
</video>
```

My jQuery call:
      $('video').mediaelementplayer();

Comment: I had the same problem.  When I moved the webm source above the mp4 source it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Chrome 11 is the first version to have H.264 removed so things might be a little tricky with how it reports what it can and can't play. I'll switch over to the dev channel of Chrome and see if I can see what's going on.

It might be better to file a bug over at https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement since this isn't really an implementation issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I think. The first jQuery code I used to init the player was this:

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video-player',{});
player.play();
```

Then I changed it to this and it worked:

```
$('#video-player').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(player, node) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    }
});
```

hth

Comment: As an aside. I was trying to get the .play() method to work in Chrome and found that the video was never loading. I found that if I changed <video preload="none" .../> to <video preload="auto" .../> that it would finally autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

I changed preload on the video tag to "auto" and it works. I'm running chrome 27